# How to pass Product Description to Paypal using WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal

The Problem:
Our products are pre-owned. Therefore, we describe each product in details. This description must be shown on PayPal Invoice in order to receive the PayPal Seller's Protection.
Currently, After a successful sale, We add this description manually.

What we did so far:
We append the description to the product name. However this field has limit of chars.

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php

```
    if ( $product ) {
        $item->set_props(
            array(
                'name'         => $product->get_name() . '<p>' .  $product->description .'</p>' ,
                'tax_class'    => $product->get_tax_class(),
                'product_id'   => $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id(),
                'variation_id' => $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->get_id() : 0,
            )
        );
    }
```

Does PayPal accept a detailed description field from WooCommerce at all?
If yes, How do we pass the description field to PayPal such that it will be displayed automatically?

Thanks for your guidance,
Owen

Comment: Where is the code you sending data to PayPal - It's possible to send the description to PayPal for each product

Comment: @mujuonly question update

Comment: 'NAME'      => $line_item_title.' x '.$item['quantity'],
                            'DESC'      => $line_item_desc,
                            'AMT'       => $this->make_paypal_amount($item['line_subtotal']),
                            'ITEMURL'   => $line_item_url

Comment: @mujuonly sorry but it looks like your answer is not related to our question

Comment: there is nothing passing to paypal in your question

Comment: @mujuonly we added the product description to the product name on checkout. later this will be sent to paypal. we do receive the description on the title name (limited to 127 chars). Now, take a look and understand the question. If you claim that paypal accepts a separate description field, kindly post a link to the doc. Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/ pass as custom variable using this hook woocommerce_paypal_line_item